# How can I select time-range with lubridate package

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

How can I subtract data by time using lubridate package???

I'm working with a dataframe in R and I want to subtract a subset by time after "2016-06-01".

My data time format is "yyyy-mm-dd" and its class is Date.

I'm trying to subtract using lubridate package like:

```
data[ymd(data$date)>='2016-06-01']
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: The line of code you have given should work. What happens when you try and use it?

Comment: It says that "It is a dataframe whose number of colums are 0 and number of rows are 41081". I can't know exactly what massage came out cause I'm using korean version of R

Answer (score 2):

To subset a matrix or data frame in R you have to use two arguments within single brackets `[]`, separated by a comma. The **first argument specifies the rows**, and **the second specifies the columns**, stylized as

```
data[ROWS, COLS]
```

So to keep the rows matching your predicate, use

```
data[ymd(data$date) >= "2016-06-01", ]
```

Comment: It works without error massage but it says the number of rows are 0

Comment: What does `max(ymd(data$date))` and `min(ymd(data$date))` say?